# Admob Ads slows down windows phone app

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, admob

I am using Admobs ads for my windows phone 8 app which is having a full screen WebBrowser component. But my app slows down deadly in the presence of ads and works normal without them.

I have added Ads from `MainPage.xaml` file. 
Is there some other way to put Ads like in some other thread or something which doesn't slows down the app. Also can having a WebBrowser component be a reason slowing down the app or its slows down always.

And can I set Refresh rate of ads manually?

Please help. App works deadly slow.

Comment: Admob est really worst ad in windows phone. Bad fill rate, generate crash and slow application. Just use pub center ;D

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can set the refresh rate manually...

Did you try,    IsAutoRefreshEnabled = true in your xaml?

I've got no idea why is it getting slow, but it works fine for me.

Comment: there is no IsAutoRefreshEnabled option.

Comment: this is the code i tried..
            <UI:AdControl IsAutoRefreshEnabled="True" ApplicationId="test_client" AdUnitId="Image480_80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="80" Margin="410,610,-30,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480"/>

Comment: Thanks for the code. This is PubCenter Ads I believe and not Admob

Comment: Ah yeah I believe. Sorry it's for PubCenter.

Comment: As i read [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/intermediate#wp) it says you can specify the refresh rate on the server from 30-120 seconds.